# Css: overflow scroll doesn't work

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am tring to put overflow scroll property into a div, in order to show a scroll bar for the user, but it doesn't work.

I don't know where is the problem.

My code is here : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gg9dL/

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="col">
            <div class="box-5">
                <div class="box-menu">
                    <img src="src/ui_dashboard/img/ic_action_twitter.png" id="imgIntoMenu"><span id="textMenu">Tweets from</span>
                    <div class="listTweets">
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                        <div class="tweetItem" id="tweetItem">toto</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.containerBloc {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 280px;
}

.box-1,.box-2,.box-3,.box-4 {
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}

.box-1,.box-2 {
    height: 200px;
}

.box-1,.box-3 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 350px;
}

.box-2,.box-4 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 200px;
}

.box-5 {
    margin: 1%;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
    float: right;
    height: 204px;
    width: 98%;
}

.box-menu {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    height: 40px;
    color: #B0B0B0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
}

#imgIntoMenu {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#textMenu {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

.tweetItem{
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    height: 70px;
}

.listTweets {
    overflow : scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to set a height to the div or else it will expand to the height of its contents

```
.listTweets {
    overflow : scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gg9dL/1/

Comment: Not that setting a height in % may not work, it works fine using `vh`though.

Comment: How would someone add a scrollbar to a `div` that is deep inside a dialog layout with size controlled by "flex"?  There's no fixed height and it's not practical to add `height` to every surrounding `div` but the scrollbar is necessary because the space is likely not large enough for its text content.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add an explicit height to your .listTweets

```
.listTweets {
    overflow : scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Updated example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gg9dL/3/

Answer (score 1):

Overflow: hidden hides everything outside of visible area. Use overflow:scroll to display the scrollbars. If you want a specific scrollbar to display, use overflow-x or overflow-y.